# return a single digit in strings (python 3)

Tags: python

make_position_string(length) 
takes the length of the state and returns
a string 01234... to be displayed in the interaction to make it easier for the
user to pick the position of the pair to be moved:

> > > make_position_string(18)
> > >       ’012345678901234567’

and thats my works:

def make_position_string(length):

```
new = []
for i in range(length):
    print(i, end = "")
    new += str(i)
return new
```

it can show up the numbers in string like this: make_position_string(12)
01234567891011['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '0', '1', '1'], so how to make it just return digit in ones like the example. I know i need to use [-1] but i have no idea where/how to use it. Can someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, it can be done with the `[-1]` but you'll need it in 2 places to use your code the most direct way

```
new = []
for i in range(length):
    print(str(i)[-1], end = "")
    new += str(i)[-1]
return new
```

If you are just interested in creating `new`, you can use a list comprehension

```
new = [str(i)[-1] for i in range(length)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The modulo operator (`%`) might help here. The "ones" digit of a number is simply the remainder when the number is divided by 10. (For example, 17 divided by 10 is 1 with a remainder of 7. Thus `17//10` is 1 while `17%10` is 7.)

Try this:

```
new += str(i%10)
```

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation
- https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Answer (score 0):

Building on what others have posted, using the modulo operator `%` is the way to go. Consider building a list and concatenating in the end, since building an (immutable) string by appending chars one-by-one is O(length^2):

```
def make_position_string(length):    
    return ''.join([str(i%10) for i in range(length)])
```

Even if it might not be too relevant if you only have faily short strings, `join` and list comprehension seems the [best](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/).